# PDO::FetchAll method override makes it fail

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, php-7

I'm working with a Firebird Database with a charset set to `NONE` that makes the PDO connection encoding not work at all, so I have to encode/decode all the data myself with code.

So what I have done was override the `PDOStatement` class and override the `bindValue()` and `fetch()` methods for automatic encoding/decoding data selectively as the snippet bellow shows, it works great, however I ran into a problem, whenever I try to override the `fetchAll()` method it returns `NULL`
even if I do not make any changes to it at all.

```
public function bindValue($parameter, $value, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR) {

    if(DB_GLOBAL_UTFENCODING && $data_type == PDO::PARAM_STR)
        $value = mb_strtoupper(utf8_decode($value));

    return parent::bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type);
}

public function fetch(int $fetch_style = null, int $cursor_orientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, int $cursor_offset = 0) {
    if(DB_GLOBAL_UTFENCODING && $fetch_style == PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )
    {
        $row = parent::fetch($fetch_style, $cursor_orientation, $cursor_offset);

        if(!$row)
            return false;

        array_walk_recursive(
                            $row, function (&$value) {
                                $value = utf8_encode($value);
                            }
                    );
        return $row;

    }
    else
        return parent::fetch($fetch_style, $cursor_orientation, $cursor_offset);
}
```

The Code above works as expected, but the override example below (where any changes are made) just never works, if I just remove the override the script works again.

I tried to look for the `fetchAll` source code but I could not find out what could be the problem.

If someone have a solution for my encoding problem even by other ways I would be glad to try it.

```
public function fetchAll(int $fetch_style = null, $fetch_argument = null, array $ctor_args = array()) {
    return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument, $ctor_args);
}
```

This snippet bellow is one of my attempts of overriding it.

```
public function fetchAll(int $fetch_style = null, $fetch_argument = null, array $ctor_args = array()) {

    if(DB_GLOBAL_UTFENCODING && $fetch_style == PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )
    {
        $rows = parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument, $ctor_args);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            array_walk_recursive(
                                $row, function (&$value) {
                                    $value = utf8_encode($value);
                                }
                        );
        }
        return $rows;

    }
    else
        return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument, $ctor_args);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered fixing your database? Treat the source, not the symptoms.

Comment: I tought about it, but its at a point that I cannot fix it, since this is a webservice for a legacy software that already has lots of data in it, and all my attempts of changing the charset all breaks the database.

Comment: Clearly not since you're already able to "fix" it on a small scale with `utf8_en/decode`, so just put your site into maintenance mode, **backup everything**, then run UTF8 encoding on the whole thing. Job done.

Comment: You need to return the parent result: `return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument, $ctor_args);`

Comment: That would be a solution, however this is not for a single site, this webservice will run at many diferent clients, and changing the charset of the database will break the other software that uses it.

Comment: Ah excuse me @chumkiu i was returning it already, I just forgot to put it in the snippet.

Comment: I Managed to resolve my issue by creating a method that iterates `fetch()` but thats not the solution I was looking forward, isn't anybody here interested in why the `fetchAll` method doesn't work when it is overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it looks like `PHP:PDOStatement->fetchAll` method does not get happy if you pass arguments that are not being used, I have done it like the snippet bellow and it works.

```
public function fetchAll(int $fetch_style = null, $fetch_argument = null, array $ctor_args = array()) {
    return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style);
}
```

What I have done as a final solution, so my override doesn't break standard use was to check whether or not those arguments are their defaults.

```
public function fetchAll(int $fetch_style = null, $fetch_argument = null, array $ctor_args = array()) {

    if(DB_GLOBAL_UTFENCODING && $fetch_style == PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )
    {
        $rows = parent::fetchAll($fetch_style);

        foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
            array_walk_recursive(
                                $row, function (&$value) {
                                    $value = utf8_encode($value);
                                }
                        );
            $rows[$key] = $row;
        }

        return $rows;

    }
    else
    {
        if ($fetch_argument !== null)
            return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument);
        else if ($fetch_argument !== null && $ctor_args == array())
            return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style, $fetch_argument, $ctor_args);
        else
            return parent::fetchAll($fetch_style);
    }
}
```